# updated user and session in symfony2.8

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working with symfony 2.8 and i'm trying to do :

If a user connect for the first time, a popup appear. I have a field "last_login" so what i did is to see if "last_login" is null and display the popup. But the problem is that my vue is generated after last_login is set so it doesn't work. What i tried then is to create a listener :

```
class firstLoginModalListener
{
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        if ($eventArgs->getEntity() instanceof User) {
            if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('lastLogin')) {
                if($eventArgs->getOldValue('lastLogin')==null){
                    //do something here 
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But even before trying this I have to know how to send the information to my twig so I tried this (just to test the communication between the twig and the listener) :

```
class firstLoginModalListener
{
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        if ($eventArgs->getEntity() instanceof User) {
            $session = new Session();
            $session->start();
            $session->set('name','test');
            $session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profile updated');
        }
    }
}
```

and tried several things in my twig :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
                console.log('{{ flashMessage }}')
            {% endfor %}
            alert('ok')
        })
    </script>
```

and :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log('{{ app.session.get('name') }}')
        })
    </script>
```

But both gave me empty result (I'm pretty sure the user is updated)

Comment: Are you using FOS user bundle or something hand rolled?

Comment: yes, we have an entity `User extends FosUser` @OKsure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your issue is that you're creating a new session instead of injecting the current one. However, rather than extrapolate Doctrine events which are quite complex and listen to too many events for what you need, you should add a subscriber to the Symfony Security component's `InteractiveLoginEvent`. Give it a priority that will catch it before the `FOS\UserBundle\Security\InteractiveLoginListener` does.

```
app.event.listener.first_login_listener:
    class: App\Event\Listener\FirstLoginListener
    arguments: ['@session']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin, priority: 10 }
```

Then set the session before last_login is set:

```
<?php

namespace App\Event\Listener;

class FirstLoginListener
{
    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    private $session;

    /**
     * @param Session $session
     */
    public function __construct(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    /**
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        if ($user instanceof UserInterface && $user->getLastLogin() === null) {
            $this->session->set('welcome', 'Welcome to your account');
        }
    }
}
```

Regarding the twig bit, try just `{{ dump(app.session) }}` and take it from there.